# Extending the Indexer for an existing class

Tags: f#

Suppose I have type A with indexer implemented, e.g. type A is a library. Now I want to extend the indexer of it, e.g. here I want to add float number into the indexer.

I worked out the following code:

```
type A(a:int array) = 
  member this.Item
    with get(x) = a.[x]
    and  set(x) value = a.[x] <- value

type A with
    member m.Item with
     get(x:float) = m.[x |> int]
     and  set(x:float) v = m.[x |> int] <- v
```

But it seems not working:

```
let a = A([| 1;2;3 |])
a.[1]
a.[1] <- 10

a.[1.0]
```

For the last line, I get:

```
Script1.fsx(243,4): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    float
```

Is extending indexer possible in F#? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This behaves differently when the type extension is defined in a separate assembly (or separate module) and when it is in the same module as the type definition.

- When both are in the same module, F# compiles them into a single class and `Item` becomes a standard overloaded indexer - In this case, your code works as expected (and this is how you actually wrote it here).
- When they are in separate modules, F# compiles the indexer as an extension member. In this case, I get the error message you described.

Adding new overloads using extension members (e.g. new method) is possible. As far I can see, the [specificaton](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf) doesn't say that this shouldn't work for indexers, so I think it is a bug (can you report it to *fsbugs* at *microsoft* dot *com*?)

Comment: Thanks Tomas! I've sent an email to FSharp Bug Reports.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this in FSI and it seems to work. 
What compiler are you using? 
This is what I fed to FSI:

```
type A(a:int array) = 
  member this.Item
    with get(x) = a.[x]
    and  set(x) value = a.[x] <- value

type A with
    member m.Item 
      with get(x:float) = m.[x |> int]
      and  set(x:float) v = m.[x |> int] <- v

let a = A([| 1;2;3 |])
a.[1] <- 10
printfn "%A" a.[1.2]
```

This prints '10'